# Create a global settings file in an open source rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a rails app and have it on github, but I'm running into some trouble separating out personal settings from what I check in to git. Just like how you typically check in a database.yml.example and let people make their own database.yml, I wanted to do that with a bunch of other files (all rb files though), like secret_token and production.rb, but I didn't feel like making the setup process involve copying 15 sample files to files that actually get used.

What I ended up doing was creating a settings.yml.example file in my config dir, and putting all of those settings from the other files in there. then the setup process was just 2 copies (database.yml and settings.yml). Then I added this to the beginning of environment.rb

```
#allow files to read their private settings from settings.yml using SETTINGS
require 'yaml'
SETTINGS = YAML.load(IO.read(Rails.root.join("config", "settings.yml")))
```

and when I needed something from the file, I would just say something like

```
Foo::Application.config.secret_token = SETTINGS["secret_token"]
```

This worked fine until I tried to run rake test, when it gave me uninitialized constant Rails (NameError) from the Rails.root.join call

My question is is this a good way to accomplish what i'm trying to accomplish? And if so, is there a better place to put the code that loads the settings file? It seems like I can load it before each individual call and just add something like "unless settings is defined" after the load, but that would be annoying to have to do everywhere

Note: For anyone who's curious, the files I would have had to copy were

- secret_token.rb
- production.rb (for config.action_mailer.default_url_options)
- devise.rb (for config.pepper)
- I expect more in the future as i start using more libraries (still new to this)

Comment: Both [**figaro**](http://www.plugingeek.com/repos/laserlemon/figaro) and [econfig](http://www.plugingeek.com/repos/elabs/econfig) (by the creator of carrierwave and capybara) are great gems for that purpose. I personally use figaro with it's `config/application.yml` file that is excluded from version control to great success since a few months on open-source projects.

Comment: I used figaro and it worked like I wanted. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this was answered in a comment, so I'll copy Thomas's answer here to make it more clear.

Both [figaro](http://www.plugingeek.com/repos/laserlemon/figaro) and [econfig](http://www.plugingeek.com/repos/elabs/econfig) (by the creator of carrierwave and capybara) are great gems for that purpose. I personally use figaro with it's config/application.yml file that is excluded from version control to great success since a few months on open-source projects.